# Is it possible to build a confidence interval a covariance matrix or bootstrap samples of observed covariance matricies?

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, covariance-matrix

Is it possible to build a confidence interval for a covariance matrix?
Matrices are the generalization of numbers.

We are 95% confidence the true covariance matrix is in Point Estimate Covariance matrix $\pm constant \cdot Variance Matrix$

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64162892/how-to-use-parametric-bootstrap-to-calculate-covariance-matrix

https://www.jstor.org/stable/23114968